# Keep clusters even at a very high zoom level, googlemaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using the marker clusters library for gmaps v3.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

I want the markers to always be clustered even at high zoom levels.

But every time I zoom enough they decluster.

Is there a way to force them to stay clustered if they are between say 1 km? No matter how much you zoom in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could tinker with the `maxZoom` option when you create a `MarkerClusterer`: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js#L39

I'm not recalling whether you want a higher or lower number but I'm sure you can figure that out pretty quickly.